# Date not getting converted from one timezone to another

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to convert IST Date to America/Los_Angeles TimeZone and then to Asia/Singapore TimeZone using Java; But I am getting wrong Date. Below is my code to parse.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateStr = "2022-03-20 15:14:00";
        Date date = sd.parse(dateStr);
        Date newDate = convertDateAsPerTimeZoneFormatForRegions(date, "America/Los_Angeles", "Asia/Singapore", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(newDate);
}
```

```
private static Date convertDateAsPerTimeZoneFormatForRegions(Date inputDate, String oldTimeZone, String newTimeZone, String timeFormat) {
        ZoneId oldZoneId = ZoneId.of(oldTimeZone);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = inputDate.toInstant().atZone(oldZoneId).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println("America/Los_Angeles : " + localDateTime);
        ZoneId newZoneId = ZoneId.of(newTimeZone);
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat);
        ZonedDateTime newDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(newZoneId);
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat);
        sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(newTimeZone));
        Date toDate = null;
        try {
            toDate = sd.parse(format.format(localDateTime));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toDate; //should get Mon Mar 20 17:44:00 but returning Sun Mar 20 00:14:00 IST 2022
}
```

I have modified the code as per comment suggestions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateStr = "2022-12-22 02:00:00";
        Date date = sd.parse(dateStr);
        convertDateAsPerTimeZoneFormat(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles", "Asia/Singapore", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

```
public static void convertDateAsPerTimeZoneFormat(Date date, String oldTimeZone, String newTimeZone, String timeFormat) {
        ZonedDateTime oldZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(oldTimeZone));
        ZoneId newZoneId = ZoneId.of(newTimeZone);
        ZonedDateTime newZonedDateTime = oldZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(newZoneId);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String oldDateTime = formatter.format(oldZonedDateTime);
        String newDateTime = formatter.format(newZonedDateTime);
        System.out.println("Old Date Time : " + oldDateTime);
        System.out.println("New Date Time : " + newDateTime);
}
```

Comment: First of all don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` in 2023. They were obsoleted nearly 10 years ago because badly designed and too troublesome to work with. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Second, a `Date` object never had a time zone, so it seems to me that you are asking the impossible. Use the modern `ZonedDateTime`. As the name says, it has one.

Comment: *//should get Mon Mar 20 17:44:00 but returning Sun Mar 20 00:14:00 IST 2022* That doesn't make sense. `Date` does not have a format. What is happening is that a format is being applied together with the time zone which you are not controlling

Comment: whats the point of using SimpleDateFormat/Date alongside LocalDateTime? Use one library or the other, and preferably java.time

Comment: @g00se - I have modified the code, the limitation being that I will only get Date and TimeZones in the input. Hence, I have converted the Date into ZonedDateTime. Is this the right way to do? I have checked the output and it is coming right for current date but incorrect for some past Date like - 2022-12-22 02:00:00

Comment: OK you need to tell us the inputs *and* expected output. Also it doesn't make much sense having a `void` method. It should possibly return `String`

Comment: Does your new code give the expected result? Please tell us the desired output and the observed output. You are still mixing old and modern APIs and thereby overcomplicating things for yourself.

Comment: The result I get from your new code seems correct to me. Involving the old and poorly designed `Date` class remains a detour with no benefits, and I uphold my best recommendation to leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( "2022-03-20 15:14:00".replace( " " , "T" ) )        // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object, after modifying input to comply with standard ISO 8601 format.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )                      // Uses a `ZoneId` to determine a moment. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) )  // Same moment, different wall-clock time. Returns another new `ZonedDateTime` object rather than altering the original, per immutable objects.
```

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use the terrible legacy classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

You said:

> I am trying to convert IST Date to America/Los_Angeles TimeZone and then to Asia/Singapore TimeZone using Java;
>
> "2022-03-20 15:14:00"

Your string input is merely a date with time-of-day, but no time zone nor offset-from-UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-03-20 15:14:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

That does not represent a moment, without the context of time zone. You say we are certain this was meant to represent a moment in `IST`. By `IST` did you mean Ireland Standard Time? Or did you mean India Standard Time? Given your profile page, I'll assume the latter.

Stick with [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region`. For India, that would be `Asia/Kolkata`.  The 2-4 character pseudo-zones like `IST` should be used only for presentation the user, never for data storage, data exchange, logging, or business logic.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = ldt.atZone( zKolkata ) ;
```

See that same moment as it would appear on someone's clock in the west coast of the US.

```
ZoneId zLosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLosAngeles = zdtKolkata.withZoneSameInstant( zLosAngeles ) ;
```

See that same moment as it would appear on someone's clock in Singapore.

```
ZoneId zSingapore = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Singapore" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtSingapore = zdtKolkata.withZoneSameInstant( zSingapore ) ;
```

See that code run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/okehqE).

```
2022-03-20T15:14
2022-03-20T15:14+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2022-03-20T02:44-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2022-03-20T17:44+08:00[Asia/Singapore]
```

To generate text in standard ISO 8601 format extended by wisely appending the zone name in square brackets, call `ZonedDateTime#toString`. To generate text in localized format, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`. This has been addressed many times already, so search to learn more.